# How to open automatically specific file in Vim when I open any other file?

Tags: vim, tabs

Because I do not use Vim intensively every day, I tend to forget some of the useful Vim tips I found here and there (mostly on SO).

So I decided to store them in a .txt file. Cheatsheet, sort of.

But now I would like to have this file loaded (in tab 2), whenever I open any other file (in tab 1), in order to peek for a solution, if needed.

I know how to launch 2 specific files together, but not a specific file automatically with an undetermined one.

How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an autocommand:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * tabf ~/Cheatsheet.txt
```

This will open `~/Cheatsheet.txt` every time you open a file in vim